# How to concatenate the length of two collections in mongodb and get the total length of two collections in one variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Below is my code.i need to get the total length of two collections in single variable.

```
audiofiles.find(),function(err,res){
                console.log(res.length);
                var count1 = res.length;
            }
            videofiles.find(),function(err,res){
                console.log(res.length);
                var count2 = res.length;
            }
            var totalcount = parseInt(count1+count2);
            console.log(totalcount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
 var totalcount = parseInt(parseInt(count1)+parseInt(count2));
```

__

Local to global scope

```
var count1;
var count2;
audiofiles.find(),function(err,res){
                console.log(res.length);
                count1 = res.length;
            }
            videofiles.find(),function(err,res){
                console.log(res.length);
                count2 = res.length;
            }
            var totalcount = parseInt(parseInt(count1)+parseInt(count2));
            console.log(totalcount);
```

Note: this is overly verbose but it should work.  Hopefully..

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But i need to get the local variables count1 & count2 globally first ,how to get it?

Comment: Declare count1, and count2 outside the scope beforehand.  As in outside the functions that they lie locally in.  Into the 'global scope'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`count()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#count)** method to return the number of documents in a collection. Since it is an asynchronous method, you can use an async library to get the sum of the results returned from
the two calls or you can use promises.

Consider the use case for the [node-async](https://github.com/caolan/async) package which includes a number of functions for dealing with situations like this, using the waterfall API:

```
var totalcount;
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        audiofiles.count({}, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            callback(res);
        });
    },
    function(count1, callback){
        videofiles.count({}, function(err, count2) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            totalcount = count1 + count2;
            callback(null, totalcount);
        });
    }
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result); // result = totalcount
});
```

Or using Promises

```
var totalcount,
    count1 = audiofiles.count(),
    count2 = videofiles.count();

Promise.all([count1, count2])
    .then(function (counts) {
        function add(a, b) { return a + b; };
        totalcount = counts.reduce(add, 0);
        console.log(totalcount); 
    })
    .catch(function (err) {})
```

Without the above, nesting the async calls (not recommended as it can potentially create callback hell):

```
var totalcount;
audiofiles.count({}, function(err, count1) {
    if (err) throw err;
    videofiles.count({}, function(err, count2) {
        if (err) throw err;
        totalcount = count1 + count2;
        console.log(totalcount);
    })
})
```